# Expo Calendar createEventAsync Not Working

Tags: react-native, expo

I keep getting `Event with id XXX-XXX-XXXX was not saved` but not sure why

I have the permissions and actually had this working before but now can't get anything to show up on the calendar

```
const event = await Expo.Calendar.createEventAsync(Expo.Calendar.DEFAULT, {
  "endDate": "2018-06-13T07:44:24.088-05:00",
  "startDate": "2018-06-13T08:00:24.496-05:00",
  "title": "PUSH",
})
```

I'm running an iOS simulator, Expo 26.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Turned out I must have not allowed Calendar access before and it wasn't asking me anymore, so it wasn't working

Cleared the device and it asked me for permission and everything worked fine from there

Comment: I have the same problem as you described above, but even making sure that having the right permissions didn't help - did you do something else as well?

Answer (score 0):

**Run this code for Calendar permission:-**

```
_askForCalendarPermissions = async () => {
    const response = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CALENDAR);
    const granted = response.status === "granted";
    return granted;   };
```